# How to PIVOT table with variable data in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

All,

```
rownum  respnum   q2        q3
-----------------------------------
1       33        Missy     155-4
2       46        Melissa   55-98
3       73        Emma      998-4
```

How would you PIVOT the above table to show the desired results below? Keep in mind the original column headers are static (q2,q3,...) but the answers can vary.

```
 rownum respnum   question  answer
-----------------------------------
1       33        q2        Missy
1       33        q3        155-4
2       46        q2        Melissa 
2       46        q3        55-98
3       73        q2        Emmat
3       73        q3        998-4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UnPivot** would be more performant, but if you don't want to specify all the fields, consider the following:

**Example**

```
Select rownum
      ,respnum
      ,C.*
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select question = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,answer   = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('rownum','respnum')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
rownum  respnum question    answer
1       33      q2          Missy
1       33      q3          155-4
2       46      q2          Melissa
2       46      q3          55-98
3       73      q2          Emma
3       73      q3          998-4
```

Comment: @J.Pyz Happy to help.  Yes we mix a little XML in there.  I tend to use this technique for discovery or if I need to unpivot a smaller sample

Answer (score 1):

Using **[UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)**, we can do this like:

```
select * from 
(select 
    rownum, 
    respnum, 
    Q2=Cast(q2 as varchar(max)),
    Q3=cast(Q3 as varchar (max)) 
 from sample)src
unpivot
( answer for question in ([q2],[q3]))up
```

<kbd>**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/RQY90368)**</kbd>

Comment: My first thougt as well.  However, "answers can vary" indicated (to me) variable data types

Comment: Edited my answer to accommodate the varying data types

Comment: May not have been necessary given the small sample.  You should add back your original   +1